# Postgresql arbitrary queries

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have pgAdmin 4 and PostgreSQL 10.

I can't execute a query without quote marks i.e. I want to excute this

```
select * from table
```

but it only works if I use

```
select * from databasename."table"
```

How can I remove this restriction?

The name of the table is `Complexitie`. I was using postgresql the last year and I remember I could write queries in a simple way without mandatory syntax things like case senstive, mandatory quotes.

I read something about to setup arbitrary SQL queries en Postgres, but I can not find steps to configure it. thanks

Comment: What's the actual name of the table?

Comment: There are reserved words like "table", "int", "sum" etc that can be used as identifiers only if enclosed by quotes.

Comment: You probably created those tables with double quotes which [makes them case-sensitive](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) `"Person"` is a different name than `Person`. I recommend to never use double quotes in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, the name of the table is Complexitie, I was using postgresql the last year and i remember I could write queries in a simple way without mandatory sintaxis things like case senstivie, mandatory quotes, I read something about to setup arbitrary sql queris en postgre, but I can not find steps to configure it. thanks

Comment: As I said: you created the table using double quotes (e.g. `create table "Complexitie" (...)`) and thus the table name is now case sensitive and you are forced to use the double quotes all the time. The best thing would be to re-create the table(s) **without** double quotes: `create table Complexitie (...)`. You can also check the many answers regarding that on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+quoted-identifier)

Answer (score 0):

You probably used a keyword as name of your table. You will find the complete list of those keywords in [that page of the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

From my experience, the most frequent ones are columns named `end` or `start`.

Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks for you answer, the name of the table is Complexitie, I was using postgresql the last year and i remember I could write queries in a simple way without mandatory sintaxis things like case senstivie, mandatory quotes, I read something about to setup arbitrary sql queris en postgre, but I can not find steps to configure it. thanks

Comment: Oh, don't use case sensitive names for objects in Postgres or you indeed will have to use quoted identifiers.

Comment: as written in documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

`Key words and unquoted identifiers are case insensitive`